# Casting const void* to const int*

Tags: c++, casting, const-correctness

I haven't used void* and const_correctness before so I am not understanding what I am doing wrong in the below code. All I want is to cast a void* returned by a member function of a const object to int*. Please suggest better approaches. Thank you.

I get the following error

```
passing 'const MyClass' as 'this' argument of 'void* MyClass::getArr()' discards qualifiers
```

So here's the actual program that I had problem with

```
 class MyClassImpl{
    CvMat* arr;
    public:
        MyClassImpl(){arr = new CvMat[10];}
        CvMat *getArr(){return arr;}
};
class MyClass{
    MyClassImpl *d;
    public:
        const void *getArr()const{ return (void*)d->getArr(); }

};
void print(const MyClass& obj){
    const int* ptr = static_cast<const int *>(obj.getArr());
}
int main(){
    MyClass obj1;
    print(obj1);
}
```

Only the methods such as 'print()' in this case know the datatype returned by 'getData'. I can't use templates because the user doesn't know how MyClass is implemented. Thank you. Feel free to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Here is how you cast a void* to an int*... (int*)vp;  Done.  That said, why are you mucking around with void* pointers like this in C++ anyway?  Templates my friend, templates...

Comment: Thanks  Ed. How can I apply templates in this case?

Comment: @Ed: yep, got it .. I am changing my code. I don't know why I didn't think about templates. thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is not in the cast from your array to a `void *` but in trying to call `obj.getArr()` when `obj` is marked `const` and `MyClass::getArr()` is not a `const` member function.  If you change your definition of that member function to

```
 const void *getArr() const { return static_cast<const void*>(arr); }
```

Then this error should resolve itself.  You might want to do a const-overload as well:

```
 const void *getArr() const { return static_cast<const void*>(arr); }
       void *getArr()       { return static_cast<      void*>(arr); }
```

Comment: That worked, but I don't want to have const on the member function because there are other functions that change 'arr' through 'getArr'

Comment: @user521771- You can do this by making the signature `void* getArr() const;`  However, you really should be thinking about whether this is a good idea - you're effectively lying about the constness of `MyClass` if you can mutate it even though it's const.

Comment: thanks templatetypedef. ya there's definitely something wrong with the design. also do u have any suggestions on how I can avoid void*

Comment: @user521771- That really depends on the design, and without more information I don't know how much I can help.  One question is why you're doing the cast to `void*` in the first place at all... why not just hand back an `int*`?

Comment: I've added more to the code. Let me know what you think is wrong with the design