# Why type casting of const void* is legal in C not C++ without using static_cast

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast, static-cast, const-cast

There are a couple of questions with similar names on StackOverflow, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48779142/casting-a-const-void) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730503/casting-const-void-to-const-int) .etc

However, none of them answered the questions in my mind...

## Problem Background:

I'm including a C header file in C++ code. The problematic C code is shown below:

```
// C header file
static inline bool post_request(const customer_t *requester, const void *packagevoid)
{
    const pkg_req_t *pkg = packagevoid;
    ...
    ... // some other code
}
```

The compiler complained that:

```
/<project_path>/handler_util.h:250:26: error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'const const pkg_req_t*' {aka 'const pkg_req_s*'} [-fpermissive]
const pkg_req_t *pkg = packagevoid;
                       ^~~~~~~
```

I changed the conversion to explictly use `static_cast`:

```
// C header file: fixed
static inline bool post_request(const customer_t *requester, const void *packagevoid)
{
#ifdef __cplusplus
  const pkg_req_t *pkg = static_cast<const pkg_req_t*>(packagevoid);
#else
   const pkg_req_t *pkg = packagevoid;
#endif
    ...
    ... // some other code
}
```

## Questions:

1. `const pkg_req_t *pkg = packagevoid;` --- why this is legal in C but giving error in C++?
2. Is static_cast an elegant solution in this case? --- I'm asking this question because it appears that `const_cast<pkg_req_t*>reinterpret_cast<const pkg_req_t*>` also works. Which one is better?
3. In the compilation error message, why is the compiler reporting "[-fpermissive]" in the end of the error message?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages with different rules.

Comment: Your `const_cast` is useless btw, removing `const` to store it in pointer to `const`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why this is legal in C but giving error in C++?

In C++, implicit conversion from `void*` to `T*` is not allowed because it is not a "safe" conversion. Dereferencing the `T*` would cause undefined behaviour unless the `void*` actually did point to a `T` object.

By the time C++ was created, it was too late to ban this type of implicit conversion in C because it would break all the code that does this:

```
T* p = malloc(sizeof(T));  // malloc returns void*
```

Therefore, it continues to be allowed in C.

> Is static_cast an elegant solution in this case?

Yes, that's the "best practices" way to perform a conversion from `const void*` to `const T*`.

`static_cast` is less dangerous than `const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`, so it should be preferred over them. `dynamic_cast` is less dangerous than `static_cast`, but it cannot be used in this situation.

> In the compilation error message, why is the compiler reporting "[-fpermissive]" in the end of the error message?

The compiler is telling you that if you compile your code with the `-fpermissive` flag, it will accept the implicit conversion from `const void*` to `const T*` even though the standard does not allow it.

Comment: Using `reinterpret_cast` is also a way to warn/spot that that cast is not secure. whereas `static_cast` won't raise so much attention from reviewer IMO.

Comment: Why `dynamic_cast` cannot be used in this situation?

Comment: @ZuckerReis `dynamic_cast` only performs safe conversions. There is no way to safely check whether a `void*` points to the desired type.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` only works on class types with at least one virtual function.